# Postgresql CASE put in the same row

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I made a query useful for my need :

```
select distinct min(term1_id), term2_id,
      case when distance = 0 then term2_id end as dist0,
      case when distance = 1 then term2_id end as dist1,
      case when distance = 2 then term2_id end as dist2,
      case when distance = 3 then term2_id end as dist3,
      case when distance = 4 then term2_id end as dist4,
      case when distance = 5 then term2_id end as dist5,
      case when distance = 6 then term2_id end as dist6,
      case when distance = 7 then term2_id end as dist7,
      case when distance = 8 then term2_id end as dist8,
      case when distance = 9 then term2_id end as dist9,
      case when distance = 10 then term2_id end as dist10,
      case when distance = 11 then term2_id end as dist11,
      case when distance = 12 then term2_id end as dist12,
      case when distance = 13 then term2_id end as dist13,
      case when distance = 14 then term2_id end as dist14,
      case when distance = 15 then term2_id end as dist15
 from graph_path
 group by term2_id, distance
 order by term2_id;
```

Put it return the results in "rows" like this:

```
Term1_id dist0  dist1   dist2
1         1
1               5
1               118
1               12823
1               40006
1                        6
1                        7
```

How can i put everything in one row like this?

```
Term1_id  dist 0 dist1 dist2
    1       1      5     6
    1       118    7     etc...
```

Is there a way to make it compact? Instead of creating a row for each dist?

Comment: No need for that DISTINCT, your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select term1_id, 
       max(case when distance = 0 then term2_id end) as dist0,
       max(case when distance = 1 then term2_id end) as dist1,
       max(case when distance = 2 then term2_id end) as dist2,
       max(case when distance = 3 then term2_id end) as dist3,
       max(case when distance = 4 then term2_id end) as dist4,
       max(case when distance = 5 then term2_id end) as dist5,
       max(case when distance = 6 then term2_id end) as dist6,
       max(case when distance = 7 then term2_id end) as dist7,
       max(case when distance = 8 then term2_id end) as dist8,
       max(case when distance = 9 then term2_id end) as dist9,
       max(case when distance = 10 then term2_id end) as dist10,
       max(case when distance = 11 then term2_id end) as dist11,
       max(case when distance = 12 then term2_id end) as dist12,
       max(case when distance = 13 then term2_id end) as dist13,
       max(case when distance = 14 then term2_id end) as dist14,
       max(case when distance = 15 then term2_id end) as dist15
 from graph_path
 group by term1_id
 order by term1_id;
```

Based on the logic in the query, I think you actually want to aggregate by `term1_id`.